# Installing HTK Error

Tags: installation

I am having an issue when I try and make the file, ./configure worked perfectly fine for me
when I try and make:

```
    zodiac@Zodiac:~/Downloads/htk$ make all
    (cd HTKTools && make all) \
           || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zodiac/Downloads/htk/HTKTools'
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zodiac/Downloads/htk/HTKTools'
    (cd HLMTools && make all) \
              || case "" in *k*) fail=yes;; *) exit 1;; esac;
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/zodiac/Downloads/htk/HLMTools'
    make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/zodiac/Downloads/htk/HLMTools'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey were you able to find a solution to this? i'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an error and it may mean that you have already run `make` once.

Try either:

```
make install
```

or

```
make clean 
make all   
make install
```

The first one will put the build files in the directory you specified in the 
`./configure --prefix=' '`. The second removes .o files and runs a fresh `make` and `make install`.

**Short explanation**: The compiler looks for object files (*.o) in the directory (and subdirs `HTKTools` and `HLMTools`). If these are up-to-date with their dependencies (i.e. their *.c files have not changed) then `make` skips building rules and the call has no effect. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561640/make-nothing-to-be-done-for-all